# custom field inside of an include

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to include a custom field from wordpress inside of a php include.

Heres what the custom field call looks like:

`<?php the_sub_field('icon_number'); ?>`

What I want to do, is place this code inside of a php include path.

So heres what it would look like manually:

`<?php include("svgs/icon-1.php"); ?>`

So combined I have:

`<?php include ('svgs/icon-' . the_sub_field('icon_number') . '.php'); ?>`

Some reason it is just spitting out the number instead of the include path.

Heres my second attempt using a variable:

```
<?php
     $iconNumber = the_sub_field('icon_number');
     include ('svgs/icon-' . $iconNumber . '.php');
?>
```

Still same output, just the numbers.

Did I mess something up?

-Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`get_sub_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) not [`the_sub_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/). Generally speaking, the `get_` functions will return a value for you to use, and `the_` functions will forcefully *echo* the value that's returned.

Comment: oh gosh i am so dumb lol this worked. thanks! ill mark as answer when it lets me

Comment: Haha we've all had variables spat out in random places now and then. Cheers!